# How to plot Peirce Quincuncial and Spilhaus maps in R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I am trying to project shapefiles of world maps in Peirce Quincuncial and Spilhaus. Although the projection is applied without errors, the plot function doesn't work. It seems something to do with the limits of the bbox

```
library(sf)
map=sf::st_as_sf(rworldmap::countriesCoarseLessIslands)
#Spilhaus
map_proj <- st_transform(map,crs = st_crs("ESRI:54099"))

plot(map_proj$geometry)
```

> Error in plot_sf(x, ...) :    NA value(s) in bounding box. Trying to
> plot empty geometries?

```
ggplot()+geom_sf(data=mappa_proj)
```

> Error in `calc_limits_bbox()`: ! Scale limits cannot be mapped onto
> spatial coordinates in `coord_sf()`.

How can I use these projections in R?

References:
https://proj.org/operations/projections/peirce_q.html
https://epsg.io/54091

Comment: Looks to be fairly complex to attempt as of 2022, although there is some documentation for a function `//toPeirceQuincuncial//` on [this github repo for user cspersonal](https://github.com/cspersonal/peirce-quincuncial-projection) that looks promising. I'd like to give it a try sometime - I will share my results here if I do.